# add list in popupwindow

Tags: android, android-listview

I have to make an application where I have to show a list of names in popup.

I have used array-list to fetch the values from database, but I cannot put it in array-adapter.

here is my code:

```
public class Calculator_new_Pop extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{ 

... // rest of the code
ArrayList<String> wallAreas=new ArrayList<String>();

wallAreas=GenericDAO.getWallAreas(room_id);//to fetch the values from databases


ArrayAdapter<String> new_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Calculator_new_Pop.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wallAreas);
                 _ltvw.setAdapter(new_adapter);

... // rest of the code
}
```

the error is

> "The constructor ArrayAdapter(Calculator_new_Pop, int, ArrayList) is undefined"

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use activity context

```
ArrayAdapter<String> new_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityName.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wallAreas);
```

You can pass the activity context to the constructor of `Calculator_new_Pop` and use the same instead of `Calculator_new_Pop.this`

Edit

```
 Context mContext; 
 public Calculator_new_Pop(Context context)
 {
      mContext = context;
 }
```

Then

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> new_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wallAreas);
```

Have a look at the constructor of ArrayAdapter.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link 
[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

ArrayAdapter needs a context as a parameter, you are supplying Dialog instance which is not the Context type, this is the reason why an error is shown. Instead of Dialog instance get the activity context.

You can pass the activity context in the constructor of the dialog, and hence supply that context in the ArrayAdapter.

```
public class Calculator_new_Pop extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{ 
Context mContext =null;
public Calculator_new_Pop(Context c ){
this.mContext = c;}

.............
.............
.............

ArrayList<String> wallAreas=new ArrayList<String>();

wallAreas=GenericDAO.getWallAreas(room_id);//to fetch the values from databases


ArrayAdapter<String> new_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wallAreas);
                 _ltvw.setAdapter(new_adapter);

.......
}
```

When instantiating dialog from activity, pass `this`.

Answer (score 0):

i am getting 'null' in "mContext"
so i tried this..

```
public Calculator_new_Pop(Activity parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(parent);

        this._act = parent;
//      
    }


_ltvw.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(_act,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,data));
```

---

it worked..